# Format of URL's in HP's Service Manager web client?

Tags: hp, service

What is format of URL in HP's Service Manager web client?
Is it possible to show the requset info by request_id passed as url parameter?
Like in JIRA or modern bug-tracking systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give you an example from our ServiceManager install. There's no guarantee it will work with yours, since you don't tell us what version you're talking about.

https://servicecenter.company.com/sc/index.do?ctx=docEngine&file=probsummary&query=number%3D%22IM1692933%22&action=&title=Incident%20IM1692933&queryHash=e5b9bbcd

The incident number is IM1692933. I have no idea what the queryHash is doing.